# Angularjs 2.0 doesn't load templateUrl

Tags: typescript, angular

I am new for `Angularjs-2.0`. I have created a sample application,and have an issue in loading `templateUrl`.

My **app.ts** file:

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'grid.html'
})
class AppComponent { }
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

I change the path like `./grid.html` but it doesn't work for me too.

Someone help me..!

Comment: did you try with full path???

Comment: @DurgpalSingh yup  but its not working..

Comment: An error message would be nice. If it is in the network tab then probably it's a path issue.

Comment: either you are using wrong URL path or try using template property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your directory structure is like this:

```
|- app
   |- grid.html
   |- component.ts
   myApp.ts
```

Then use `templateUrl: 'app/grid.html'`.

### Update

The solution above makes us hardcode `app/` in every place to include these files. So here is another one:

1. Define `"module": "commonjs"` in file `tsconfig.json`
2. Add a new line `moduleId: module.id,` to the `@Component` decorator.

So it becomes:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'grid.html'
})
```

Reference:

- [Angular cannot find templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563678/angular-cannot-find-templateurl)
- [Angular2 beta relative paths for templateUrl and styleUrls](http://schwarty.com/2015/12/22/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls/)