# Angular cannot find templateUrl

Tags: angular

I am trying to load Html files using the following code in angular js 2.
This file is available under products folder and the html file that i am trying to load is also in the same folder. Still it is not working.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl:'./products/app.component.pen.html'
})

export class PenComponent
{

}
```

The above file is getting loaded from the below AppComponent.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import {PenComponent} from "./products/app.component.pen";
import {BookComponent} from "./products/app.component.book";  

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <header>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['Pen']">Pen</a></li>

                <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['Book']">Book</a></li>
                </ul>

            </header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]

})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/pen', name: 'Pen', component: PenComponent, useAsDefault:true}
    {path: '/book', name: 'Book', component: BookComponent}


])


export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: please use single quote in - `'./products/app.component.pen'`. with every import.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Are you able to load `PenComponent`? Do you get any error ? if yes, which?

Comment: templateUrl doesn't work like import you have to give full path from starting folder e.g. `app/products/app.component.pen`

Comment: @micronyks - If i have some text in template instead of templateurl its working fine.

Comment: @Dimple. Its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to use paths relative to the root of the project for styleUrls and templateUrls (so `app/foo/bar/products/app.component.pen.html` instead of `./products/app.component.pen.html`).

To use urls relative to the component file, your project must be a `commonjs` module (set `"module":"commonjs"` in tsconfig), and you have to include `module.id` in your component decorators:

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'foo',
  moduleId: module.id // <== need this
  templateUrl: './foo.html'
})
```

Comment: A reference to the docs would have been nice. Upvote, though :-)

Answer (score 2):

Its shown [here](http://schwarty.com/2015/12/22/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls/) that relatives path works but i think that that are nor release yet.
You have to use full path from starting folder. For e.g. if your start folder name is `app`. You have to give path as:
`templateUrl:app/products/app.component.pen`