# Failed to load app.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

When i use `templateUrl` in `@Component` I get the following error in browser console.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'http-app',
  directives: [
  ],
  templateUrl: "app.html",
})
class HttpApp {
}
```

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load app.html
>
> resolvePromise@http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6504:33
>   makeResolver/<@http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6481:15
>   ApplicationRef_http://localhost:8080/common.js:9943:26
>   [616]/http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6289:21
>   NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvoke@http://localhost:8080/common.js:10351:33
>   [616]/http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6288:21
>   [616]/http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6182:26
>   scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6537:54
>   [616]/http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6322:25
>   NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8080/common.js:10342:33
>   [616]/http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6321:25
>   [616]/http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6222:30
>   drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6440:27
>   ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6392:23

Project arh.:

```
Test
-app
--css
--img
--ts
---components
----login
-----login.ts
-----login.html
----services
---app.ts
---app.html
---vendor.ts
--index.html
```

Comment: Where is located your `app.html` file? Could you provide your project organization?

Answer (score 1):

According to your error, it seems that the path to your template in the `templateUrl` attribute isn't correct.

Note that such paths are relative to the root of the project for `styleUrl` and `templateUrl` attributes.

I think that you could try something like that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'http-app',
  directives: [
  ],
  templateUrl: "app/app.html",
})
class HttpApp {
}
```

See this question for more details:

- [Angular cannot find templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563678/angular-cannot-find-templateurl)

Comment: I try write like templateUrl: "app/app.html", and  templateUrl: "./app/app.html", but have this problem

Comment: Where is your template file located from the boot folder of your project?

Comment: app.ts it is boot file. It is example from book ng2. All examples don't use  templateUrl. I don't know why it happens.